# How to catch the error from a stored procedure? in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, parameters, try-catch

I have a stored procedure which can return a error this example its going to return error always

```
create proc regresaerror
as
begin
 raiserror 51001 'Error al borrar los precios especiales' 
end

declare @error varchar(max)
set @error=''
begin try
set @error=exec regresaerror
end try
begin catch
end catch
```

I tried it (because I need insert this error in a temporary table) but that block code get this error

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'exec'.*

Stored procedure couldn't be updated for add a output variable

Then how can I catch the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st solution:

```
BEGIN TRY
    EXECUTE regresaerror
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH;
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) is link to MSDN.

2nd solution:

```
create proc regresaerror 
(
  errmsg varchar(max) out
)
as
begin
 set errmsg =  'Error al borrar los precios especiales' 
 return 51001 -- if error
end 

declare @error varchar(max)
declare @numerror int
set @error=''   
exec @numerror = regresaerror @error out
```

Comment: umm i couldn't update the proc or drop and create it again, for my this is a store working for other process, then we couldn't do changes to it

Comment: for instructions of boss i couldnt do changes to the store proc